# ¿Cómo divido esta cadena después de la palabra extraída con la expresión regular?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, validación

```py
import re

input_text_to_checkA = "to play football in the street you need good boots" #For example

regex_patron_00A = r"\s*\¿?(?:so you can play |so you can play |to play the |to play )\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??"
regex_patron_00B = r" \s*((?:\w+\s*)+) \s*\¿?(?:are really necessary the |are really necessary |would be needed from |would be needed |she needs |he needs |you need )\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??"
mA = re.search(regex_patron_00A, input_text_to_checkA, re.IGNORECASE)
if mA:
    input_text_to_checkB = mA.group() # ---> "football in the street you need good boots"

    mB = re.search(regex_patron_00B, input_text_to_checkB, re.IGNORECASE)
    if mB:
        word, association = m.groups()
        word = word.strip() # ---> "football in the street"
        association = association.strip() # ---> "good boots"
```

Necesito `input_text_to_checkB = ""` para almacenar la cadena sin el comienzo de lo que era válido en la primera expresión regular y sin lo que estaba almacenado en la variable work.

Lo que necesito es que en input_text_to_checkB tenga la cadena de entrada inicial pero sin la coincidencia de la primera expresión regular y sin lo que queda en la variable word, por ejemplo si input_text_to_checkA es igual a "to play football in the street you need good boots" es necesario eliminar la coincidencia del primer regex "to play" y lo que queda almacenado en word "football in the street" quedando `input_text_to_checkB = "you need good boots"`.

El problema es que como no se que validacion de la regex tengo que quitar y tampoco cual es lo que se almacenara en word, estoy en duda de como plantear la regex.

Comment: Realiza un `split` y quédate con la segunda parte de esa operación

Comment: Ahi le edite, y me queda `word = to play football in the street`  y  `association = good boots`  , solamente word esta mal porque habria que quitar la coincidencia que se dio en lregex_patron_00A quedando solamente ` word = "football in the street"`, ahi no se como plantear el `split` que mencionas porque el principio que debo quitar puede ser cualquiera de las opciones del regex, y ademas si o si debo hacerlo en 2 regex separadas que no tengan 2 secuencias de opciones `"(?: )"` dentro de la misma regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la solución más simple para evitar un *bucle infinito de backtracking* sería usar una expresión regular que simplemente contenga todos los "inicios de frase" (pero no intente capturar "el resto") y otra que tenga todos los "separadores de frase" ("you need", etc) pero que tampoco intente capturar nada de lo que va delante ni de lo que va detrás.

Estas serían las expresiones regulares a que me refiero, que en realidad casi ni son expresiones regulares, salvo por el uso del `|` (quiero decir que no intentan usar comodines):

```
regex_patron_00A = r"(?:so you can play |so you can play |to play the |to play )"
regex_patron_00B = r"(?:are really necessary the |are really necessary |would be needed from |would be needed |she needs |he needs |you need )"
```

Una vez tenemos esto preparado, la idea es la siguiente:

1. La frase de entrada se divide en trozos usando `re.split()` con la primera expresión regular. El resultado tendrá dos trozos (lo que aparezca antes de "to play", por ejemplo, que será en general una cadena vacía, y lo que aparezca después de "to play", que será el resto de la frase que intentabas capturar con tu expresión regular original).
2. Si no se consiguen dos trozos, se rechaza la frase.
3. Si todo va bien, al segundo trozo se le aplica de nuevo un `re.split()` con la segunda expresión regular. De nuevo saldrán dos trozos: lo que hubiera antes del "you need" y lo que haya después.
4. Si no se consiguen aquí dos trozos, se rechaza la frase. Si se consiguen, esos dos trozos son lo que buscabas.

En código:

```
import re

def extraer(frase):
  regex_patron_00A = r"(?:so you can play |so you can play |to play the |to play )"
  regex_patron_00B = r"(?:are really necessary the |are really necessary |would be needed from |would be needed |she needs |he needs |you need )"
  x = re.split(regex_patron_00A, frase, re.IGNORECASE)
  if len(x)!=2:
    return False
  x = re.split(regex_patron_00B, x[1])
  if len(x)!=2:
    return False
  return x
```

He hecho que la función retorne False si la frase no cumple el patrón. Ejemplos:

```
ejemplos = [
            "to play football in the street you need good boots",
            "to play volleyball in the beach you don't need good boots",
]
for ej in ejemplos:
  print(repr(ej), "-->", extraer(ej))
```

produce:

```html
'to play football in the street you need good boots' --> ['football in the street ', 'good boots']
"to play volleyball in the beach you don't need good boots" --> False
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda